# Navigate backward and forward icons not visible in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using the Visual Studio 2022 version 17.2.5. But I cannot see Navigate Backward and Forward buttons. I cannot see any option to make them visible as well.

VS 2022:

[image]

Other VS:

[image]

I am also not able to navigate using ctrl+- and ctrl+shift+- as well.

There are no options here also.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be controlled via the View → Toolbars → Standard control (which you currently have disabled it seems).  Once you enable that, they should reappear, along with the rest of the "Standard" controls.

Comment: Once your toolbar is present again, you can also right click in a blank space within it to toggle other toolbars.

Comment: But why is it not visible by default now? It used to be default behaviour earlier

Comment: @viveknuna I couldn't tell you.  I am pretty sure when I installed VS 2022, they were present.  Maybe you somehow accidentally disabled it.